# Are there substances people can put on themselves to prevent catching fire?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, safety

This can be very useful for people who are afraid of spontaneous human combustion! But seriously, I heard there are non-harmful chemicals used in some fire extinguishers, so can they maybe be put on our skin, clothes, etc. in advance to prevent ever catching fire?

Comment: The general class of chemicals you're interested in are called *flame retardants*, substances which are used on clothing already.  I'm not sure that it would be practical to smear them on your skin unless you're planning on doing something unwise near a fire.  Firefighters already use substantial protective equipment, and smoke inhalation is typically a bigger danger for them.

Answer (score 7):

It depends *how long* one is exposed to heat, and *how hot* the source is, but yes, there are "fire retardants" for skin:

1. A mix of alcohol (ethanol or isopropanol) and water or [butane in soap sud can be set afire on your palm without burning you](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FTLuO2b2DBg), if done **very carefully**. The water soaks up heat energy both because of its high [specific heat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity) and through evaporation.
2. Insulation applied to the skin or [between skin and flame](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dcUhxIbXZSk) can protect (momentarily) from a torch.
3. A wet hand is [*temporarily* protected from molten lead](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTOCAd2QhGg) by the [leidenfrost effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leidenfrost_effect). As water on the skin boils, it acts, briefly, barrier to the heat.

**NB: Do not try these experiments yourself (or on others). You get *no* points for being a crispy critter.**